Phone Call, Settings, Chrome, and Play Services apps are shown with dual messenger orange circle on Samsung
On a Samsung Galaxy A13, I have the following app icons Phone Call, Settings, Chrome, and Play Services all showing the orange dual messenger circles. But when I check the dual messenger settings, it shows four apps that are available to be used, but none are actively being used. Could I be seeing these icons from someone previously using dual messenger and then turning it off, or is there something else that can cause this to happen?
There is a secure folder on the phone that has Chrome, but when I check that there's the regular Chrome, then the secure folder Chrome with the blue icon on the bottom, and then this Chrome with the orange icons. I have seen in the storage a work profile section that I don't know what's for. When I check accounts, there's no work account. Could a hidden app cause this to happen?
I hope there's enough details that someone might be able to help me with this. I am very confused on this. Any input would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

As a lone user of a Samsung device with Dual Messenger feature, AFAIK it's normal that some non-messenger apps are included to support the messenger apps, even if they are not shown on the app launcher.
